# Creating Instance of Python Extension Type in C

Tags: python, extension-modules

I am writing a simple `Vector` implementation as a Python extension module in C that looks mostly like this:

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    double x;
    double y;
} Vector;

static PyTypeObject Vector_Type = {
    ...
};
```

It is very simple to create instances of `Vector` while calling from Python, but I need to create a `Vector` instance in the same extension module. I looked in the documentation but I couldn't find a clear answer. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest is to call the type object you've created, e.g. with [PyObject_CallFunction](http://docs.python.org/c-api/object.html#PyObject_CallFunction) -- don't let the name fool you, it lets you call *any* callable, **not** just a function.

If you don't have a reference to your type object conveniently available as a `static` global to your C module, you can retrieve it in various ways, of course (e.g., from your module object with a [PyObject_GetAttrString](http://docs.python.org/c-api/object.html#PyObject_GetAttrString)).  But sticking that `PyObject*` into a `static` module-level C variable is probably simplest and most convenient.

Comment: When I call Vector_Type, what function is it actually calling? Do I pass the same arguments that you would normally use to create an instance from Python? Do I also need to Py_INCREF() the returned PyObject* from PyObject_CallFunction?

Comment: When you call a type (or any other callable) from C via a `PyObject_Call...` function in the Python C API, it will go through exactly the same steps (and require exactly the same arguments) as when called from Python.  The docs I pointed to clearly say _Return value: New reference._ meaning that you don't need to incref it (understanding new, borrowed and stolen references is crucial to programming to the C Python API, and the docs are always commendably super-explicit about what case applies!-).